# I need to iterate over each line of this file, adding each of the values from each line together in Bash

Tags: bash

Here's the file:

```
90     88     80      70
80     90     67      89
70     81     78      85
88     79     90      78
67     66     80      90
80     60     90      89
```

so for example, I would need to add 90, 88, 80, and 70 together from the top row.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this quite easily with awk:

```
$ cat numbers.txt 
90     88     80      70
80     90     67      89
70     81     78      85
88     79     90      78
67     66     80      90
80     60     90      89

$ awk '{print $1+$2+$3+$4}' numbers.txt 
328
326
314
335
303
319
```

Answer (score 3):

Here comes a funky pure Bash solution:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -ra line; do 
  numbers=($line)
  echo $(IFS=+; echo "$((${numbers[*]}))")
done < foo.txt
```

As suggested by another user, this can be shortened to:

```
while read -ra numbers; do 
  echo $(IFS=+; echo "$((${numbers[*]}))")
done < foo.txt
```

As suggested by another user, one `echo` can be removed by using a compound statement instead of a command substitution statement:

```
while read -ra numbers; do 
  (IFS=+; echo "$((${numbers[*]}))")
done < foo.txt
```

Since this is tagged only Bash it might be a worthwhile solution.

As per suggestion by @anishsane a variant without modify IFS in a subshell:

```
while read -r line; do echo $(( 0 $(printf "+%s" $line) )); done < file
```

Comment: Good answer. Here is another variant of your answer, without modifying `IFS` in subshell. `while read -r line; do echo $(( 0 $(printf "+%s" $line) )); done < file`

Comment: @anishane: I really like your answer. Great solution.

Comment: Feel free to include it in your answer as 'another variation'.

Comment: Also, I did not understand, why you needed to convert `:` to `<space>` (`${line//:/ }`). There are no `:` in the input file.

Comment: @anishsane: Yes you are right, this was by my mistake working on some snippet to created an associated array. See my corrected answer.

Comment: @anishsane: Can I squeeze in the line 2 `numbers=($line)` into line 3 somehow instead of using `numbers`?

Comment: You can simplify the first solution: `while read -ra numbers; do (IFS=+; echo "$((${numbers[*]}))"); done < foo.txt`

Comment: I don't know of a way to combine line 2 and line 3. line2 separates the string into array elements with whitespace as the delimiter. And then line3 combines them back to string with `+` as delimiter.

Comment: @Dzienny: This does work correct. I'm not sure if this is less readable and obvious to the user. What do you think? I added your comment to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @stephanmg Also notice that one of the `echo` can be removed, if you slightly change the structure..

Comment: @Dzienny: Do you mind suggestion the necessary change? It seems I cannot in short.

Comment: @stephanmg Sure, take a closer look at the code I sent previously, the solution is there.

Comment: @Dzienny: I updated my post and need to rediscover the differences between the two mechanism. Thanks! Could you explain why the first echo can be removed? `()` will just run the code in a subshell, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping

Answer (score -1):

The below sums regardless of the number of columns.

```sh
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
    read -a pa <<< "$p"
    {
        echo "0"
        for i in "${pa[@]}"
        do
            echo "$i"
            echo '+'
        done
        echo "p"
    } | dc
done < filename.dat
```